# How to test whether a JavaScript object is an ordered type of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, collections

I'm looking for an efficient way to test whether or not a JavaScript object is some kind of ordered object. Hopefully someone knows a trick that doesn't involve writing some huge type assessor function. Fortunately, I don't have to deal with IE < 9 so most of the newer methods are OK.

The fundamental problem is this: I need to figure out whether or not to run a **for** loop or a **for...in** loop on an object. However, I don't always know if the object is going to be an object literal, an array, a jQuery object, etc.

Here are some of the obstacles I'm running up against:

I clearly can't only use `typeof` because both arrays and objects return `object`.

I clearly can't only use `Object.prototype.toString.call(collection)` because, while arrays do return `[object Array]`, custom ordered collections such as jQuery objects still return `[object Object]` and the whole reason I want this test is to determine whether I need a **for** loop or a **for...in** loop. Using a **for...in** loop on a jQuery object includes properties that aren't actually part of the collection and messes things up.

I did come up with one idea that looks like this:

```
function isOrdered(item) {

    // Begin by storing a possible length property
    // and defaulting to false for whether the item
    // is ordered.
    var len = item.length, isOrdered = false;

    // Functions are an easy test.
    if (typeof item === 'function') {
        return false;
    }

    // The Arguments object is the only object I know of
    // with a native length property that can be deleted
    // so we account for that specifically too.
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(item) === '[object Arguments]') {
        return true;
    }

    // Attempt to delete the item's length property.
    // If the item is ordered by nature, we won't get
    // an error but we also won't be able to delete
    // this property.
    delete item.length;

    // So if the length property still exists as a
    // number, the item must be an ordered collection.
    if (typeof item.length === 'number') {
        isOrdered = true;
    }

    // If we originally stored a custom length property,
    // put it back.
    if (len !== undefined) {
        item.length = len;
    }

    // Return the result.
    return isOrdered;
}
```

So far this technique has passed all of my tests but I'm worried about possible performance hits that could arise from deleting properties on custom objects and I'm not 100% confident I'm not missing something. Does anyone have any better ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by collection? Is it array?

Comment: What about using Array.isArray to determine what you are working with? http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#Array.isArray

Comment: Phoenix: By "collection" I mean any collection of data whether that's an object literal, an array, or something else. Gopherkhan: Array.isArray isn't good enough because custom ordered objects such as jQuery objects still return false.

Comment: Then what about jQuery's makeArray? http://api.jquery.com/jquery.makearray/

Comment: Because $.makeArray simply takes an object literal and puts it into a new array. What I need to do is determine whether the object is ordered or not. I don't want to convert it into something else.

Comment: If "the whole reason I want this test is to determine whether I need a for loop or a for...in loop", then would you be better served by using `jQuery.each` instead the loop constructs (as it already handles this problem)?

Comment: @tjdett That's a good suggestion. In reality, the only reason I mentioned jQuery is because it is a well-known example of a library that is based on custom ordered objects. In my particular case, I need to do this in vanilla JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

If your trick is working in Firefox, Chrome, and recent IE, I think it's probably okay....though a bit wonky.

Delete goes through and deletes the key and value from an object, rather than just clearing the reference. It will actually return false if it cannot delete the property, so you could tighten up your logic a bit further.

There's a bit of performance overhead to property deletion, and it does some weird stuff to regular objects currently in memory  [[see this article]](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/11/05/writing-fast-memory-efficient-javascript/), but negligible depending on the browser. It really depends on how many collections you'd be doing this on at a time. For a single array/object/mystery, I think it would be fine. But for a nested collection of thousands of arrays, you might want to look into some other alternative.

Here's a JS perf if you're primarily concerned with performance:
http://jsperf.com/delete-vs-undefined-vs-null/3

**update**
Alternatively, if you are concerned with Jquery collections vs arrays, you could do something like the following:

```
if (foo.length != undefined) {
  if (Array.isArray(foo)) {
    // regular array. Could also do 
    // foo instanceof Array
 }
 else if(foo.constructor.toString().match(/jQuery/g)) {
    // jquery collection
 }
} else {
  // not an ordered collection
}
```

Comment: Thanks, those articles are extremely helpful and they point out exactly the kind of performance overhead I was worried about. Unfortunately, just by setting a property to undefined, I'd actually be adding a new property to objects in some cases which I'd prefer not to do. I think delete is actually the only way to make this work, although I wish I didn't have to. Provided nobody disagrees in a while, I'll check this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
function isOrdered(item) {
    var len = item.constructor.prototype.length;

    return len === +len;
}
```

If 'item' is a js object this will evaluate to false but if it's an array or jQuery collection this will return true.

Note that things other than arrays can have numeric length properties (try checking the length of a function). If you might pass things like integers or functions you will need to do something more complicate, but this should catch all the cases you catch in your posted code. Also, I think deleting the length property can have unpredictable results so I would avoid that approach in favor something that does not mutate the object you are testing.

Comment: That's a cool idea. However, if I were to say `var x = {length: 4}` and then call your version of `isOrdered(x)`, I would get a false positive.

Comment: This is better but it still throws false positives for a few things. Two of those are functions and the Arguments object. Those can be accounted for easily enough but it also throws a false positive for the live and non-live NodeList objects which makes me worry there are others out there that will also produce false positives.